# When I package and run my app, there is no problem. But when I upload it to Google play and test it through audit, I will report an error

Tags: android

I can't find the reason. If you have similar experience, please let me know.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a Class not found, probably a proguard/R8 misconfiguration or something like that. Also please write your question with more details (e.g. put your logs in the question instead of an image)

Comment: try to clean your project then re-build

Comment: I don't know what I'm missing. The main reason is that I can package it with my signature and run normally. Only when I put it in the Google store and have it checked will this happen

Answer (score 0):

I probably know that I may lack a file, but what puzzles me is why I can package it to run, but it can't run when I put it in Google store. Moreover, I've been looking inside my file for a long time, and I haven't found where I need to call the corresponding. So file

[image]

[image]